# Decorator for function with optional arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I have a function my_f with many arguments (some of them can be optional), for example,

```
def my_f(a, b, opt_arg = 3):
    #do some stuff
```

Now I want to write some decorator for this function that will do some simple stuff depending on the optional argument opt_arg. I do not know the number of arguments of my_f but I know the name of the optional argument. How I can do this? Is is it possible to do in such way that both variants      `my_f(1,2, opt_arg=3)` and `my_f(opt_arg =3, 1,2,3,4)` would work correct?

Comment: I believe `my_f(opt_arg =3, 1,2,3,4)` is a SyntaxError regardless of how you try to decorate it.

Comment: You can see the default values in the tuple `my_f.func_defaults`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: the OP isn't asking for introspection here however..

Answer (score 1):

Use a `**kw` variable keywords argument in your decorator wrapper and see if `opt_arg` is present in it:

```
from functools import wraps

def yourdecorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        opt_arg = kw.get('opt_arg')
        if opt_arg is not None:
            print "opt_arg was given and set to {!r}".format(opt_arg)
        return f(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

Demo:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def yourdecorator(f):
...     @wraps(f)
...     def wrapper(*args, **kw):
...         opt_arg = kw.get('opt_arg')
...         if opt_arg is not None:
...             print "opt_arg was given and set to {!r}".format(opt_arg)
...         return f(*args, **kw)
...     return wrapper
... 
>>> @yourdecorator
... def my_f(a, b, opt_arg=3):
...     pass
... 
>>> my_f(42, 81)
>>> my_f(42, 81, opt_arg=3.14)
opt_arg was given and set to 3.14
```